# Issue while downloading images from server

Tags: ios, swift, image, download

I've received an array object from the server, and then I want to download images with one property on that object. then I want to update UI with array objects and images (view model). I'm downloading images on a background thread, but I'm getting images with delay and the object doesn't fills at all, whats I'm doing wrong?

```
func presentCoinse(_ list: Home.Models.CoinseListResponse) {
        var coins = [Home.Models.coinsViewModel]()
        for item in list {
            getImage(symbol: item.symbol) { image in
                let i = Home.Models.coinsViewModel(image: image,
                                                   symbol: item.symbol,
                                                   name: item.name,
                                                   buyPrice: item.buyPrice,
                                                   sellPrice: item.sellPrice,
                                                   change24Hource: item.symbol)
                coins.append(i)
            }
        }
        viewController?.displayCoinsList(viewModel: coins)
    }

    private func getImage(symbol: String, complation: @escaping(_ image: Data?) -> Void) {
        
        queue.async {
            if let url = URL(string: "\(CDN_URL)\(symbol).png") {
              
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    complation(data)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use URLSession instead for downloading and avoid try? since it hides any errors you might have.

Comment: I've used Alamofire and got same result.

Comment: And what error did you get then?

Comment: nothing, It downloaded Images successfully, but -> viewController?.displayCoinsList(viewModel: coins) called with empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getImage` method contains async operations, in this situation  the closure will be called after the return of the method.
And, the method `displayCoinsList(viewModel:)` is called before every async `getImage`.

You can use the [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) class.

```
func presentCoinse(_ list: Home.Models.CoinseListResponse) {
    var coins = [Home.Models.coinsViewModel]()
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() // add a dispatch group 
    
    for item in list {
        dispatchGroup.enter() // increment group counter before async call
        getImage(symbol: item.symbol) { image in
            defer {
                dispatchGroup.leave() // decrease group counter in every condition with 'defer'
            }
            let i = Home.Models.coinsViewModel(image: image,
                                               symbol: item.symbol,
                                               name: item.name,
                                               buyPrice: item.buyPrice,
                                               sellPrice: item.sellPrice,
                                               change24Hource: item.symbol)
            coins.append(i)
        }
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        // wait all async calls are completed
        viewController?.displayCoinsList(viewModel: coins)
    }
}

private func getImage(symbol: String, complation: @escaping(_ image: Data?) -> Void) {
    
    queue.async {
        if let url = URL(string: "\(CDN_URL)\(symbol).png") {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
            complation(data)
        } else {
            complation(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE: In `getImage` Method is required to call `complation` In every condition. If you forgot to call it the DispatchGroup can’t receive a notify and you’ll be blocked.**

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that you're setting coins to empty list, and then you call displayCoinstList with that empty list. the list is appened and updated asyncronically.
You should trigger the view controller to reload the coins list when it's ready. I'd make the coins list prior going to fetecg the images, and then upon receiving the images - the UIImageView will render itself.

```
    func presentCoinse(_ list: Home.Models.CoinseListResponse) {

            // async part srarts here

            var coins = [Home.Models.coinsViewModel]()
            for item in list {
                getImage(symbol: item.symbol) { image in
                    let i = Home.Models.coinsViewModel(image: image,
                                                       symbol: item.symbol,
                                                       name: item.name,
                                                       buyPrice: item.buyPrice,
                                                       sellPrice: item.sellPrice,
                                                       change24Hource: item.symbol)
                    coins.append(i)
                }
            }

            // async part ends here

            viewController?.displayCoinsList(viewModel: coins)
        }
```

What you did is equivalent to:

```
func presentCoinse(_ list: Home.Models.CoinseListResponse) {
        var coins = [Home.Models.coinsViewModel]()
        viewController?.displayCoinsList(viewModel: coins) // coins in empty at this point)

        for item in list {
            getImage(symbol: item.symbol) { image in
                let i = Home.Models.coinsViewModel(image: image,
                                                   symbol: item.symbol,
                                                   name: item.name,
                                                   buyPrice: item.buyPrice,
                                                   sellPrice: item.sellPrice,
                                                   change24Hource: item.symbol)
                coins.append(i)
            }
        }
    }
```